# Uninstall Ubuntu from free dos

Tags: partitioning, uninstall, ntfs, system, format

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a free dos laptop. I have kept the free dos partition on the system. Now I want to uninstall ubuntu and install windows 7. Windows installer disk is unable to install on the partition of ubuntu. help me guys i need to install windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

## Warning! This will erase EVERYTHING on your internal HDD

1. Inside the Windows installer, at the welcome screen (before the partitioning screen) hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.
2. At the command prompt, type `diskpart`
3. Once `diskpart` loads, (it will take a few seconds) type:

   ```
    list disk
   ```
4. Take note of the number assigned to your internal HDD
5. Then, run this command, replacing X with the number assigned to your internal HDD:

   ```
    select disk X
   ```
6. Finally, do:

   ```
    clean
   ```

---

Then, close both CMD Windows and proceed with the install.